# Hibernate JPA 2.1 dependency

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, dependency-management

I am getting 2 jars for Hibernate JPA:

- `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`
- `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`

What should I do to fix this? I just want:

```
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
```

I have the below in POM :

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hibernate-core dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

includes:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to run `mvn dependency:tree` and find which dependency is bringing you the `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar` artifact.

Afterward, you need to exclude this transitive dependency.